# How to properly define default values in a Request Body?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I have an endpoint that receives a request body with opptional fields that I want to specify a default value for:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/pass-obj", consumes = "application/json")
  public MyResponse getResponse(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) { ... }
```

with

```
public class MyRequest {
  @Schema
  String foo;
}
```

If the caller doesn't specify `foo`, its default value should be `"ba"`.
For `@RequestParameter` I know you can use `@RequestParameter(defaultValue = "ba"), so I figured, since` @Schema` offers a property of the same name, that I could just  use:

```
public class MyRequest {
  @Schema(defaultValue = "ba")
  String foo;
}
```

however, this default value gets completely ignored. Why is that?

I can of course check `foo` for `null` in `getResponse` and modify its value.
I can also initialize the field with my desired default value:

```
public class MyRequest {
  @Schema
  String foo = "ba";
}
```

but I'm not sure if this is the "right way" as it would e.g. not work with final fields and I would have expected there to be an annotation for it. Is there a better, recommended way of specifying the default value?

Comment: I don't think there is an annotation to handle this because `@RequestBody` refers to the Object and not internal elements. Also `@RequestBody` is responsible for deserializing everything from JSON to java object unless you add `@JsonIgnore`. That's why it is overriding "ba" with null. I think checking foo for null is the way. Another solution is to create custom annotation something like `@Default("ba")`. But it's a lot of work

Comment: Agreed with @Pradyskumar